# Executing scripts as XML in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am not able to execute a script by parsing it as XML as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20904288/4802288). I see that it is not supported in Synapse based on MSDN. Could someone please help me how could I achieve this in SQL DW? I have a table that have all the SQL Statements and I want to execute them by looping through each record in that column.

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE [#Temp]
(
JOB_ID INT NOT NULL,
SQL_STMNT NVARCHAR(2000)
);
```

**DML:**

```
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 100, 'SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE MyDate = @ProcessDate'
UNION 
SELECT 103, 'SELECT * FROM Table_B WHERE MyDate = @ProcessDate AND MyCode = ''ABC'''
UNION 
SELECT 110, 'SELECT * FROM Table_C WHERE MyDate = @ProcessDate AND MyID = 345'
UNION 
SELECT 200, 'SELECT * FROM Table_D WHERE MyDate = @ProcessDate'
UNION 
SELECT 230, 'SELECT * FROM Table_E WHERE MyDate = @ProcessDate'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`STRING_AGG` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
 SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(SQL_STMNT as nvarchar(max)), '; ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY JOB_ID ASC)
 FROM #Temp
);
exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Thanks Greg! Why is the `UNION ALL` in here?

Comment: What were you wanting to happen? I guess not union all the queries together into one result? Feel free to replace with semicolon (;)

Comment: No,I guess I want to loop through each record and execute them.

Comment: @Julaayi edited my answer. That should do what you want. But you could also use a while loop and ROW_NUMBER function on the temp table to literally do a loop and choose the next row. But that’s less efficient if all you are doing is executing the queries.

Comment: Thanks Greg! What if I want to do a SELECT *, '@MyVariable' FROM TABLE_A provided the '@MyVariable' is always before the FROM and I can pass that variable from Stored Procedure?

Comment: @Julaayi how about wrapping the STRING_AGG function like: `REPLACE(STRING_AGG(....), '@MyVariable', @MyVariable)`